# How to use HAVING clause in the SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables like this:

```
    // businesses
+----+---------+
| id |   name  |
+----+---------+
| 1  | foo     |
| 2  | bar     |
| 3  | baz     |
+----+---------+

// transactions
+----+-----------+-------------+----------+
| id |  user_id  | business_id |  amount  |
+----+-----------+-------------+----------+
| 1  | 10        | 1           | 3000     |
| 2  | 11        | 1           | 2500     |
| 3  | 10        | 2           | 4000     |
| 4  | 10        | 2           | 2000     |
| 5  | 11        | 3           | 3000     |
| 6  | 10        | 1           | 5000     |
+----+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

Also, I have these queries:

#1:

```
SELECT b.name, (select count(1) 
                   from (select count(1) num
                           from pos_transactions pt where pt.business_id = b.id group by user_id
                        ) x
               ) the_number_of_unique_customers_num 
FROM businesses b

+------+------------------------------------+
| name | the_number_of_unique_customers_num |
+------+------------------------------------+
| foo  | 2                                  |
| bar  | 1                                  |
| baz  | 1                                  |
+------+------------------------------------+
```

#2:

```
SELECT b.name, (select count(1) 
                   from (select count(1) num
                           from pos_transactions pt where pt.business_id = b.id group by user_id
                           having num > 1   -- this is added
                        ) x
               ) the_number_of_unique_customers_have_had_more_than_one_trans 
FROM businesses b

+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| name | the_number_of_unique_customers_have_had_more_than_one_trans |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| foo  | 1                                                           |
| bar  | 1                                                           |
| baz  | 0                                                           |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

As you can see, those two queries are very similar. Only `having` clause added to the second one. Now, I want to combine them, I mean, having just one query for both of them. Here is the expected result:

```
+------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| name | the_number_of_unique_customers_num | the_number_of_unique_customers_have_had_more_than_one_trans |
+------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| foo  | 2                                  | 1                                                           |
| bar  | 1                                  | 1                                                           |
| baz  | 1                                  | 0                                                           |
+------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: You are right @forpas .. I will edit my question

Answer (score 1):

Start by using aggregation to summarize the `transactions` table:

```
select business_id, count(*) as num_users,
       sum(num_transactions > 1) as num_users_gt_1
from (select user_id, business_id, count(*) as num_transactions
      from pos_transactions
      group by user_id, business_id
     ) t
group by business_id;
```

Then join in the names:

```
select b.*, bb.num_users, bb.num_users_gt_1
from businesses b left join
     (select business_id, count(*) as num_users,
             sum(num_transactions > 1) as num_users_gt_1
      from (select user_id, business_id, count(*) as num_transactions
            from pos_transactions
            group by user_id, business_id
           ) t
      group by business_id
     ) bb
     on bb.business_id = b.id;
```

Comment: Seems good .. thank you .. I will give it a try .. the key of your answer is "summarize first"

Comment: I guess you must add one `group by business_id` inside the `bb` .. Am I right?

Comment: @stack . . . And in the first query too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `LEFT` join of the tables and 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT name, 
       COUNT(*) the_number_of_unique_customers_num,
       SUM(counter > 1) the_number_of_unique_customers_have_had_more_than_one_trans
FROM (
  SELECT b.id, b.name, t.user_id, COUNT(*) counter
  FROM businesses b LEFT JOIN transactions t
  ON t.business_id = b.id
  GROUP BY b.id, b.name, t.user_id
) t
GROUP BY id, name
```

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ it is simpler with aggregation and window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.name, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY b.id) the_number_of_unique_customers_num,
       SUM(COUNT(*) > 1) OVER (PARTITION BY b.id) the_number_of_unique_customers_have_had_more_than_one_trans
FROM businesses b LEFT JOIN transactions t
ON t.business_id = b.id
GROUP BY b.id, b.name, t.user_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf470157df70f040129f4ed62489f7d0).
Results:

| name | the_number_of_unique_customers_num | the_number_of_unique_customers_have_had_more_than_one_trans |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 2 | 1 |
| bar | 1 | 1 |
| baz | 1 | 0 |

Comment: This is your second answer under my question that has a window-function version too ... and still I cannot understand how window function works in your queires ..

Comment: @stack in this case I admit that mixing aggregation and window functions is complicated. But window functions are very helpful. You can find here an introduction: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/

Comment: For example, why `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY b.id)` .. and not `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY pt.user_id)` ?

Comment: @stack because `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY b.id)` counts users for each business id but `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY pt.user_id)` counts business ids for each user_id.

Comment: Oh I see .. also, do you think can `COUNT(DISTINCT(pt.user_id))` be an alternative for `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY b.id)` ?

Comment: @stack the group by clause in my query contains `t.user_id` so each group is a unique combination of business and user. In this case `COUNT(DISTINCT pt.user_id)` would always return 1. So, no, this is not applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query

```
select rt.name,lt.the_number_of_unique_customers_num,rt.the_number_of_unique_customers_have_had_more_than_one_trans 
from (select t1.business_id,count(*) as the_number_of_unique_customers_num 
     from (select distinct user_id,business_id from pos_transactions) t1 join businesses t2 on t1.business_id = t2.id group by t1.business_id) lt

join

(select t1.id,t1.name,isnull(t2.the_number_of_unique_customers_have_had_more_than_one_trans,0) as the_number_of_unique_customers_have_had_more_than_one_trans
   from businesses t1 left join (select user_id,business_id,count(distinct user_id) as the_number_of_unique_customers_have_had_more_than_one_trans from pos_transactions group by business_id,user_id having count(user_id)> 1) t2 on t1.id = t2.business_id) rt on lt.business_id = rt.id
```